# Why when adding items to combobox it's adding the same item many times?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the top of form1:

```
public class ComboboxItem
        {
            public string Text { get; set; }
            public object Value { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return Text;
            }
        }

        List<string> results = new List<string>();
```

Then:

```
ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
var result = videoCatagories.Execute();

for (int i = 0; i < result.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                item.Text = result.Items[i].Snippet.Title;
                item.Value = result.Items[i].Id;
                comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
            }
```

And in the end:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show((comboBox1.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem).Value.ToString());
        }
```

What i wanted to do in general is to add to the combobox the titles and then when i select a title to get the title id.
For example i run the program and select the title Weather now i want to see in a messageBow.Show the id 1

There are 31 items.
When i use a breakpoint and look on result i see 31 items when i click on the first item in index 0 i see Id = "1" and then i click on snippet and see title "weather"

Then i do the same for item in index 1 and i see Id = "19" and in the snippet the title is "animals".

But for some reason it's adding each itertion the same item many times.

Comment: where is `result` coming from?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `comboBox1.Items.Add` and run it in the debugger - it's hard to tell without more context.

Comment: You are adding the same object over and over.  You must create a new ComboboxItem for each entry.

Comment: Your code changes the properties of the *same* `item` instance for each entry in `results`. I'd expect that all 31 items display the text and value of the last item in `results`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new instance of ComboboxItem each time you want to add a new item to the combo box:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.Items.Count; i++)
{
    ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
    item.Text = result.Items[i].Snippet.Title;
    item.Value = result.Items[i].Id;
    comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code changes the properties of the same item instance for each entry in results, then adds it to the `comboBox1.Items` collection. `Add` inserts its argument to the Items collection, it doesn't copy its contents. As a result, when the combobox is rendered, all combobox items point to the same item. To avoid this, create a new `item` instance for each entry in `results`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.Items.Count; i++)
{
    var item=new ComboboxItem 
             {                 
                   Text = result.Items[i].Snippet.Title,
                   Value = result.Items[i].Id
             };
    comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

or

```
var items=from item in result
          select new ComboboxItem 
             {                 
                   Text = item.Snippet.Title,
                   Value = item.Id
             };
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a simple check to make sure that the combobox doesn't already contain it before doing the insert.

```
ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
var result = videoCatagories.Execute();

for (int i = 0; i < result.Items.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if(!comboBox1.Items.Contains(item))
    {
            item.Text = result.Items[i].Snippet.Title;
            item.Value = result.Items[i].Id;
            comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Or you can do like this article suggests and remove every item that is the same before adding the new item to remove conflicts, [No Duplicate in a Listbox or using the same way to stop duplicates from a combobox too](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/442202/Csharp-Add-items-from-Combobox-to-listbox-without)